# Counting occurrences between two sides on sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have this table of "Letter_Senders":

```
> LETTER_ID | SENDER | RECIPIENT  
> 123       | John   | David  
> 234       | Josh   | Andrew  
> 345       | David  | John  
> 456       | Matt   | David 
> 567       | David  | Matt  
> 678       | John   | David
```

I would really appreciate the help for summing up the number of letters that were sent between every pair of peoples as in the following "Counting_Letters" table:

```
Person_1  | Person_2 | Num_Of_Letters
John      | David    | 3
Josh      | Andrew   | 1
Matt      | David    | 2
```

was trying to figure it out but have no idea, need to take into consideration counting from both Person sides only once.

Comment: please tag the dbms you are using.

Answer (score 2):

If your dbms supports functions like `greatest` and `least`, use

```
SELECT greatest(person_1,person_2) AS person_1,
       least(person_1,person_2) AS person_2,
       count(*) AS num_letters
FROM letter_senders
GROUP BY greatest(person_1,person_2),
         least(person_1,person_2)
```

It can also be achieved with a `case` expression.

```
SELECT CASE
           WHEN person_1>person_2 THEN person_1
           ELSE person_2
       END AS person_1,
       CASE
           WHEN person_1<person_2 THEN person_1
           ELSE person_2
       END AS person_2,
       count(*) AS num_letters
FROM letter_senders
GROUP BY CASE
             WHEN person_1>person_2 THEN person_1
             ELSE person_2
         END,
         CASE
             WHEN person_1<person_2 THEN person_1
             ELSE person_2
         END
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the same answer as vkp (working under the same assumptions):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Test') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Test

CREATE TABLE #Test
(
    LETTER_ID INT
    ,SENDER VARCHAR(20)
    ,RECIPIENT VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT #Test
VALUES
(123, 'John', 'David'),
(234, 'Josh', 'Andrew'),
(345, 'David', 'John'),
(456, 'Matt', 'David'),
(567, 'David', 'Matt'),
(678, 'John', 'David')

SELECT
CASE
    WHEN SENDER < RECIPIENT
        THEN SENDER
    ELSE RECIPIENT
END [Person_1]
,CASE
    WHEN SENDER > RECIPIENT
        THEN SENDER
    ELSE RECIPIENT
END [Person_2]
,COUNT(*) [Num_Of_Leters]
FROM #Test
GROUP BY CASE
    WHEN SENDER < RECIPIENT
        THEN SENDER
    ELSE RECIPIENT
END
,CASE
    WHEN SENDER > RECIPIENT
        THEN SENDER
    ELSE RECIPIENT
END
```

Comment: Similar to what I would have posted except I would have calculated the groups with a cte and then did a group by on that. I personally just find it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH
    letters (sender, recipient, num_of_letters) AS
    (
        SELECT
            sender
            , recipient
            , COUNT(*) num_of_letters
        FROM
            letter_senders
        GROUP BY
            sender
            , recipient
    )
SELECT
    person_1            sent.sender
    , person_2          sent.recipient
    , num_of_letters    sent.num_of_letters + received.num_of_letters
FROM        letters_sent sent
INNER JOIN  letters_sent received 
ON 
    (sent.sender = received.sender AND sent.recipient = received.recipient)
    OR (sent.recipient = received.sender AND sent.sender = received.recipient)
```